# Marshmallow Invalid input type on nesting

Tags: python, marshmallow

I wrote a nested schema. but whenever i pass the json from postman it shows invalid input type.
here is the code below:

```
class ChalanProductsSchema(Schema):
   product_id = fields.Str(required=True)


class ChalanDetailsSchema(Schema):
    chalan_id = fields.Str(required=True)
    rows = fields.Nested(ChalanProductsSchema, many=True)


   chalan_details_Schema = ChalanDetailsSchema(many=True)

# serializing json
data = chalan_details_Schema.load(json_data)


#json i pass from postman
{
"chalan_id":"2022.08.0002",
"rows":[
     {
       "product_id":"XXXXXXXX1"
     },
     {
       "product_id":"XXXXXXXX2"
     }
    ]
 }
```

Error I am having:

> {
> "_schema": [
> "Invalid input type."
> ]
> }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't expect multiple ChalanDetail

Try to change

```
chalan_details_Schema = ChalanDetailsSchema(many=True)
```

into

```
chalan_details_Schema = ChalanDetailsSchema()
```